# Jquery auto load picture

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for small piece of code, that would load first to the div.

Let's say I have small pictures on a page, with link to full resolutions, and this jquery code would load the first one to the empty div.

I've been searching this forum and googling but couldnt quite find what I was looking for.

Thanks,
Mart

Answer (score 1):

[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/H8UcJ/3/). Almost the same as @rcravens suggest.

Comment: Hi Guys, thansk the only problem I've got is, that I cant edit the img in the code, its gained thru wordpress plugin, what I get is <a class="smallpics" href="full.jpg"><img width="177" height="123" src="thumb" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="thyme" title="thyme" /></a>

Comment: should be something like this.
$("#placeholder").html("<img src='"+$("a.smallpics").first().attr("href")+"'/>");

Comment: you are welcome) if the question is solved you can chose the correct answer and push the "green check sign" on the left side of the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var src=$('#thumbs img:first').data('.link');

$('#image').attr('src',src);
```

Depends a bit upon you HTML. I assume you have the following:

```
<div id='thumbs'>
<img src='...' data-link='URL to full image' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  $("#contentDiv").append($("img").first());
});
```

This will move the first image.. to have it both original and inside div have this instead:

```
$("#contentDiv").append($("img").first().clone());
```